# Gitlab CI/CD: Schedule only for a particular job and exclude it from the pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

Consider I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`, and they are running fine in Pipeline:

```
image: 

stages:
  - job1
  - job2
  - job3
       
job1:
  dependencies: []
  stage: job1      
  script:

job2:
  dependencies: []
  stage: job2     
  script:

job3:
  dependencies: []
  stage: job3    
  script:
```

Now, what I would like to achieve is:

- to exclude `job3` from the Pipeline
- and to create a schedule only for this `job3`

I have read option to configure schedule, using `rules`, so I edit the `job3` as follow:

```
job3:
  dependencies: []
  stage: job3
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
  script:
```

And I setup a schedule. But unfortunately, it doesn't work out: `job3` is still part of the Pipeline, and my schedule runs all the jobs.

What is missing in this configuration? Or is it possible to achieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

define rules for every job:

```
job1:
  dependencies: []
  stage: job1  
  rules:  
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule"'
      when: always
  script:

job2:
  dependencies: []
  stage: job2  
  rules:  
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule"'
      when: always  
  script:

job3:
  dependencies: []
  stage: job3
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
      when: always
  script:
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is _quite_ correct as written. A default case is needed for job1 and job2 according to the condition, not for job3. Alternatively, if you invert the condition, no default would be needed for any of the jobs.

Comment: you're right, i updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add rules to **every** job to get the behavior you want.

On the jobs you want to **only** run on the scheduled pipelines,

```yaml
rules: # e.g., for job3
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
```

Because this rule will only match for scheduled pipelines, a job with these rules will only trigger on a schedule (when no rule matches, the job is excluded).

On every other job, you should add a rule with an inverse rule to have them excluded from scheduled pipelines:

```yaml
rules:  # e.g., for job1 and job2
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule"'
```

This rule should match in every case *except* when the pipeline is triggered by a schedule, meaning these jobs will be included in all non-schedule pipelines.